# Protocol Buffers under Windows C++ .Net

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have gotten google protocol buffers to work with Linux as the server, and C#.Net under windows as the client. However, I don't see a way to generate C++.net. Can someone point me to how I can do that?

Thanks.

Ivan

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a full C++ .NET implementation, and none is listed in the [3rd party add-ons](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), so I think you have a few options:

- use the **unmanaged** C++ implementation (presumably the google version), and map between your unmanaged and managed types manually
- use one of the C# implementations (protobuf-net or protobuf-csharp-port would be my preferences, depending on whether you want idiomatic .NET versus idiomatic protobuf), and compile this as a C# library, and simply reference the C# library from you C++ .NET project
- write (and ideally contribute) a C++ .NET translator to your implementation of choice (since you have tagged protobuf-net, I will make the observation that this means writing an xslt file for protobuf-net)

If you want the most pragmatic C++ option, I'd choose the first. If you want the most pragmatic .NET option, I'd choose the second. If you *demand* a proper C++ .NET file that you can include in your existing project, I'd choose the third.